# Play live h264 encoded video RTSP stream using kivy

Tags: python, kivy, python-gstreamer, openh264

I have a c++ program that uses `live555` in a winapi kernel event-loop that passes images from a camera to `libopenh264` and then served as an RTSP stream using `ffmpeg`.  The stream can be viewed fine using `VLC`. The event-loop also records to an avi container.

I wanted to setup a remote-viewing client using `kivy` using the simple kvlang below:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Video:
        source: "rtsp://ip.address:8554/stream"
        play: True
```

The window does not display a `Video` object, and the logging output has the following errors

```
[ERROR             ] [Image       ] Error reading file rtsp://ip.address:8554/stream
# ...
[ERROR             ] [VideoGstplayer] Could not open resource for reading and writing.
```

When I change the stream encoding to MJPEG, the video player displays the live video without errors. Furthermore, when I change `source` to the file-path of the h264 encoded avi file that is recorded, it plays without errors. Is there a configuration that can alert the `VideoGstplayer` of the expected encoding? Alternatively, is there a problem with my stream setup that the provided kivy player cannot read it properly? Perhaps I am missing a gstreamer dll, but the message does not alert me to anything such as that.

This was all performed on windows using the basic installation instructions for installing python-dependencies. `kivy` version being used is `1.9.1`. I am new to kivy.

**edit**: Just to bring more information to the table. It would seem that the `image`-type error still occurs even when the codec is `MJPEG`. Therefore, it would seem that the display issue is somewhere in gstremer or the implementation of gstreamer.